# How can organize an Array of NSDictionary according to dictionary's key

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

Hear me Dictionary's array:

```
(
    {
    user = PXb9Inrz77;
    key = 2;
},
    {
    user = HEjkgHbWVv;
    key = 4;
},
    {
    user = REkumLf7m5;
    key = 3;
}
)
```

How can order the array by ascending in order to key value in Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the result into an array of dictionary of type [String:AnyObject], then you can use the following code

```
let sortedResult = -NAMEOFYOURARRAYOFDICTIONARY.sort{$1["key"] as? Int > $0["key"] as? Int}

print(sortedResult)
```

and it should print it out for you in an ascending order.